# PHP: How to convert ASCII to HTML or how to decode string

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server, ascii

I have a database table (SQL Server 2008) with a table that contains some ASCII-encoded characters (formatted as `nvarchar(max)` ).

Usually the browser converts these automatically to HTML but I use a jQuery plugin that cannot read these and requires the content in HTML. I am passing my content to this plugin using PHP.

Is there a way in PHP to convert such strings manually to HTML ?

**Example - db content:**

```
&lt;p&gt;Some sample text with &lt;strong&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

**Example - required output for plugin:**

```
<p>Some sample text with <strong>HTML</strong></p>
```

I tried finding a solution myself but it seems there are different approaches available and I wasn't sure about the correct one here.

Comment: So, there are different approaches available - why not test them and see which one gives you the right results?  I really don't see any research effort put into this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try `html_entity_decode();`

```
html_entity_decode('string', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is the difference here compared to the other answer ?

Comment: Thanks - can you say what is the difference between ENT_QUOTES and ENT_COMPAT here ?

Comment: ENT_COMPAT, Will convert double-quotes and leave single-quotes alone. ENT_QUOTES Will convert both double and single quotes

Answer (score 2):

use this,

```
echo html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is great too. Can you tell me what is the difference here compared to the other answer ?

Comment: Nohing... here $string is php variable  where you can set your string like `$string = '&lt;p&gt;Some sample text with &lt;strong&gt;HTML&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';` in case of long string if you want...

Comment: Thanks - I mean between ENT_QUOTES and ENT_COMPAT.

Comment: ENT_COMPAT -  Will only convert double quotes and  ENT_QUOTES - Converts double and single quotes